# Making flags from the flag of Norway

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, flags

Here is the flag of Norway. You can cut out rectangular non-overlapping regions from this flag to form flags of other countries. What is the most number of different country flags you can make?

[image: Flag-of-Norway]

Comment: Idea from a Facebook post I've seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can make

> up to **9 flags!**
>
>  [image]
>
> We have 6 starting flags: Indonesia, France, Poland, Finland, Netherlands and Thailand.
>
> Ignoring differences in shading, Monaco and Luxembourg can be added, and ignoring symbols then Malta can also be added for a total of 9!

It's known as the Mother of all Flags for a reason!

Comment: Very nice! Let's see if anyone can improve on this.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky going through the wikipedia page of flags by colour combinations - would you accept singapore? Or is the symbol too important to the flag

Comment: I don't think the proportions are right for the Finnish flag. And why should we be allowed to ignore charges?

Comment: @msh210 the proportions for finland are off, but I think its fine as its still very recognisable as the flag. I think differences in shading is fine as most of these colours are off anyway (I know the france blue is definitely brighter) but the red blue white patterns are still very recognisable. Malta is the only one I'd really question whether its acceptable here - I've only included it as its the only flag which goes white-red vertically, but the missing symbol is key. Thats why I've said up to 9 flags in my answer, IMO theres defintely the 6 given, and the rest depends on the rules :)

Comment: I am flexible with dimensions and colours. But the symbols are rather important, especially if they take a considerable amount of area.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky in that case (unless I've missed something obvious) I believe this is all the countries possible, all others have large distinguishing symbols. Included Malta as the symbol is not distinguishing and the pattern is unique, the other 8 are all the colour only ones there are

Comment: -1: The part you have in the middle is very much not the Finnish flag, as the blue cross is far thicker than it is in the actual flag. The proportions in the Norwegian flag are 1:2 (white to blue), while in the Finnish flag they're 4:3 (vertically) or 5:3 (horizontally). It's not just a question of the ratios or colors being off by a bit, but already about which of the white or blue parts is thicker.

Comment: @ilkkachu it's not quite right, but close enough for the untrained flag reader :)

Answer (score 3):

The question says "cut out rectangular non-overlapping regions from this flag to form flags". Read literally, it suggests we are allowed to **form** flags from rectangular regions, not necessarily that the rectangular regions that are cut out must themselves **be** flags. If one permits reconstruction of flags from rectangular pieces cut out of the flag, I can get:

> 17 flags:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Directly stealing from BeastlyGerbil's answer, Malta, Monaco, Indonesia and Poland all require just one rectangle. I split France, Netherlands, Luxembourg and Thailand across several rectangles to address proportion issues, and Finland splits into four sections for the same reason. We also get to add:
>  Peru (2 sections, horizontally placed)
>  Austria (2 sections, vertically placed)
>  Russia (2 sections, vertically placed)
>  Costa Rica (4 sections, vertically placed; the blue splits in two parts)
>  Denmark (4 sections, on the corners)
>  Tonga, Switzerland and Iceland are a bit of a mess, but hopefully clear from the diagram.
>
>  There remains a legit question about shades of blue, as (say) the blue in the Russian flag is substantially lighter than that of Norway. But I have addressed all proportion issues: flags are constructed proportionally with the best information I could find with casual Internet searching (mostly Wikipedia).

Comment: that's very clever :)